# Are permissions on individual reports in SSRS overridden when redeployed?

Tags: security, reporting-services

Is it possible to set permissions on a report individually in the native SSRS portal?

If so, when re-publishing the reports, is the security on the individual report lost? Is there a way to avoid this in that case?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337494(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can break inheritance on the security to manage each item individually.

No, the report designer tools have no concept or knowledge of the security on the report server website

Comment: But if you have security set up on the SSRS server for a particular report, redeploying it will NOT erase your existing security. I.e., you can make changes to the report in VS and redeploy without a problem. Things like subscriptions will remain intact, too.

Comment: Is there a way to hide the reports that the users do not have access to based on the accesses?

Comment: They simply won't see the objects on the report server (reports, datasets folder) to which they don't have access.